# With a 2D vector, does calling clear() on the 1st level clear all the memory associated with that vector?

Tags: c++, memory, vector

I have a 2D vector declared as such:

```
vector<vector<uint16_t>> vector;
```

After this is used and I need to clear all memory associated with it, even the elements in the [][X] dimension, can I simply do:

```
vector.clear();
```

Or do I have to go through each of the vectors inside and call .clear() on them, before finally calling it on the main vector? If that is the case, what would be a clean solution for that?

Comment: N.B. I think we'd usually call that the first level, not the second.

Comment: *With a 2D vector, does calling clear() on the 1st level clear all the memory associated with that vector?* -- Yes.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Please do not answer in the comments section. Answers in the comments section cannot be peer reviewed. For example, I would have been able to downvote yours, because it is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since a vector neatly destructs its elements and deallocates the used memory when itself gets destructed, and `v.clear()` also destructs the elements in the vector, calling `v.clear()` is a perfectly valid way to delete an entire 2D vector.

Note that if you want also the memory for `v` itself cleaned up you need to call `v.shrink_to_fit()` after `v.clear()`.

Comment: Note that depending on how the underlying system manages memory you might not see any change in the memory consumption of the program. The memory could sit marked for reclamation but not be reclaimed.

Comment: This is not quite true. There's no guarantee that the space allocated for the inner vectors (though not their contents!) will be freed.

Comment: But.... if we talk only about logical element removal then yeah obviously you have it right and I think that's what the OP's after anyway.

Comment: `shrink_to_fit` is only a hint

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings At that point you're splitting hairs. The allocator can be a bumping allocator with a no-op `free`.  Or the allocator might never return memory to the OS. Or the OS might refuse to release this memory to other processes. Or the hypervisor for virtual machine the OS runs in might not return the memory to the host. There's no end to it.

Comment: I guess it really depends on what layer of abstraction we're willing to go to. As user4581301 pointed out, indeed it can _never_ end. Though I generally draw the line at what the vector "knows", so: did it give the memory back to the allocator? Regardless, you're currently claiming that to clean up memory "you need to call `shrink_to_fit`", even though the function need not (and often doesn't) do anything, and I think that's misleading.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings What you are discussing with orlp is much higher than my level. To elaborate on what exactly I need to be doing, I want to fully clear both levels of the vector, reallocate all the levels in first level and then store user input in the second level. In my current situation, this gives me a segfault, which I have narrowed down to this .clear() call. Is there a better way to ensure that what I need to be done is done?

Comment: If you're faulting over the `clear` call, the right thing to do here, you have another bug elsewhere. Maybe a buffer overrun that smashed the `vector` or the allocation's book-keeping information, maybe you overflowed the stack, maybe cyberninjas. Sounds like you should ask another question with a [mre] that demonstrates this misbehaviour so so we can help you round it up and kill it. Assuming making the MRE doesn't end with an abrupt a facepalm and a quick, unassisted bug fix.

Comment: @peepeepoopoo -- You have a bug in your program -- there is nothing wrong with the `clear()` function.

Comment: @user4581301@PaulMcKenzie indeed. Facepalming has occurred. Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 1):

*With a 2D vector, does calling clear() on the 1st level clear all the memory associated
with that vector?*

Yes, `clear` erases all elements from the container.

Quoting from [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/clear),

`std::vector<T,Allocator>::clear`

> After this call, size() returns zero.
> Invalidates any references, pointers, or iterators referring to contained elements. Any
> past-the-end iterators are also invalidated.

But this does not affect allocation/deallocation of internal storage in any way whatsoever. So, if you meant to ask,

*With a 2D vector, does calling clear() on the 1st level *FREE* all the memory associated
with that vector?*

No. As per standard,

> Leaves the capacity() of the vector unchanged (note: the standard's restriction on the
> changes to capacity is in the specification of vector::reserve, see [1](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/clear))

So, if you wish to free up memory, either go for `shrink_to_fit()` or better swap contents with an empty vector. This is what most but not all implementations do.

```
v.swap(std::vector<T>());
v.swap(std::vector<std::vector<T>>()); // if vector of vectors
```